# Почему меняются классы в yandex-maps-api?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Застилил balloon через классы .ymaps-2-1-65- но через некоторое время они изменились на класс .ymaps-2-1-68-
Как с этой бедой бороться?
Версия подключенная 2.1

http://take.ms/gt6qd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Версия 2.1 постоянно обновляется и ведёт на последнюю стабильную версию.
Добавлять классы через .ymaps-2-1-65 JS API Карт не рекомендует. Если вам нужно изменить стили балуна, то правильный путь это создать собственный балун:
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/balloon_autopan

Answer (score 1):

Как-то нужно было кастомный курсор навесить, сделал вот так

```
*[class*="-events-pane"]
    cursor: url("#{$path-images}/required/map-cursor.png"), auto !important
```

https://yandex.ru/turbo/internet-technologies.ru/s/articles/prodvinutye-css-selektory-o-kotoryh-vy-ne-znali.html